# Choosing the right projection using PyProj

Tags: python, shapely, pyproj

I'm starting with GIS work trying to analyze movement of cars on a track.
I've understood that in order to use a library like shapely I need to transform from GPS spherical coordinates to Cartesian and for that I need a projection.

I'm confused with how to choose the right projection. The area of interest this way or another is not big but I couldn't wrap my hand around which projection to choose from the "catalog".

Comment: What area your data covers? Most of the time, if in one country, you mostly adopt official national projection(s) from the country. They have an equivalent code in EPSG table

Comment: @ThomasG77 The area is of couple kilometers in the same country, but not the same country or location - can I have a projection built from a given gps points to describe good this specific area? Or would you advise to have some sort of dictionary between the name of the country and the right projection?